# Why can't I go to home screen from service

Tags: java, android, android-intent, handler, homescreen

*Running project on API KitKat(19) Pixel 2 with target API 30.*

I have a service that is running in the foreground, with this handler inside of it that I can confirm is running normally via the println statements I see.

```
    Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    private Runnable periodicUpdate = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.postDelayed(periodicUpdate, 1000 - SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()%500);
            currentApp = getForegroundApp();
            for (AppObject restrictedApp : allAppsRestricted) {
                System.out.println("restricted app: " + restrictedApp.packageName);
                System.out.println("foreground app: " + currentApp);
                if (currentApp.equals(restrictedApp.packageName)) {
                    showHomeScreen();
                    System.out.println("We're trying to go home");
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

I can also confirm that the current app and foreground app packages are the same via the "We're trying to go home" println statements I see.
Also in my service I have a showHomeScreen() method. The code for the showHomeScreen() method ideally takes the user out of the foreground app that matches the restricted app by showing them the home screen. Here it is:

```
    public void showHomeScreen(){        
        Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        App.getContext().startActivity(startMain);
}
```

Outside of my service I have the App class and the getContext() method my showHomeScreen() is calling:

```
public class App extends Application {
    private static Context context;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        createNotificationChannel();
        App.context = getApplicationContext();
    }

    public static Context getContext() {
        return context;
    }
}
```

I've seen the contents of my showHomeScreen() method posted as the top answer for multiple questions on how to take the user to the home screen, however it has not once taken me to the home screen. What am I missing? How do I take the user to the home screen from within my service?

Comment: You cannot start activities from the background in modern versions of Android.

Comment: I've been able to launch activities from my app from my backgoround service, just not the home screen. Not to mention, there are many apps that take users from a given foreground app to the homescreen. Take app blocking apps for instance. This wouldn't be possible if what you say is true. @CommonsWare

Comment: See [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts).

Comment: Thank you. I noticed another post where you addressed an attempted workaround to a problem like this. I am going to remove/close this question and try some alternatives, such as using a receiver class that will use the showForeground() method. @CommonsWare

Comment: @UserOne I was expecting to get an error too, but it never shows. Which is a little odd since I don't think I'm suppressing it anywhere.

Comment: @UserOne The method I'm using for getting the current foreground app seems to be working normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***DISCLAIMER: You shouldn't use this permission unless you are providing some kind of administrative or parental control type service to your users.***
but... You CAN launch your activity via a background service by putting this permission into your manifest:
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>`

And by directing the user to enable system overlays by rerouting them to settings to enable your app's overlaying activities from your background service:
`startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION));`